# Calling columns of record by it´s index, not name

Tags: plsql, record

I have table with more than 160 columns and I need to work with each column in PL/SQL procedure. I make a record of whole row from the table like this:

```
DECLARE
  l_employee rec_employees%ROWTYPE;
  COLUMN_AND_VALUE VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO l_employee
  FROM employees
  WHERE employee_id = 100;
```

and now I want to work with all columns of this record with FOR LOOP, but I don't know how, because I have to refer to each column of record by its column name like l_employee.id, l_employee.salary,.... is it possible to refer to them in order somehow like l_employee[INDEX_OF_COLUMN] and also get the name of column I am working with? Here is the example I want to do with record:

```
FOR INDEX_OF_COLUMN IN 1 .. 167 LOOP
     COLUMN_AND_VALUE := l_employee[INDEX_OF_COLUMN].COLUMN_NAME || ': ' || l_employee[INDEX_OF_COLUMN].VALUE_OF_COLUMN

-- I know those commands don't work, but I need something like that

END LOOP;
```

Or is here better way to do it without using record?

Thank you very much and I'm really sorry for my bad English. I hope you understood my question :)

Comment: Can you please help us understand the use of this? Are you really going to  process all 167 columns?
If yes, then while processing you will definitely have to give the `column name` explicitly. As I think processing of each column's data will be different than the other.

Comment: However, you can get all the column names for the table using ` CURSOR C2 is select COLUMN_NAME from `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` where TABLE_NAME ='EMPLOYEES';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found with some help this solution. It is exactly what i needed in this post, but then i realised it´s not the best way for me because of another conditions i had.

```
`DECLARE  
  l_query      VARCHAR2(32767) := 'SELECT * FROM employees where id=1';  
  l_theCursor  INTEGER DEFAULT dbms_sql.open_cursor;  
  l_columnValue VARCHAR2(4000);  
  l_status      INTEGER;  
  l_descTbl dbms_sql.desc_tab;  
  l_colCnt NUMBER;  
BEGIN  
  dbms_sql.parse(l_theCursor,l_query,dbms_sql.native);  
  dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl);  
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_colCnt  
  LOOP  
    dbms_sql.define_column(l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000);  
  END LOOP;  
  l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);  
  WHILE ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 )  
  LOOP  
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_colCnt  
    LOOP  
      dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );  
      dbms_output.put_line( l_descTbl(i).col_name|| ': ' ||l_columnValue ); 
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;  
EXCEPTION  
WHEN OTHERS THEN  
  dbms_sql.close_cursor( l_theCursor );  
  RAISE;  
END;  `
```